# How do I load millisecond accuracy dates with SQLLDR

Tags: oracle, etl, date-formatting, sql-loader, controlfile

I am trying to load date fields that have six decimal places using `sqlldr`. For example I have a date:
 `"2020-01-05-16.32.02.070000"` in my csv import file.

In my control file for sqlldr I tried:   `LASTMODIFIED DATE "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6",`

But the sqlldr throws the error:   `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

So I can change my format string to `LASTMODIFIED DATE "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS",`

The of course if fails to load because:

```
Record 43: Rejected - Error on table ORA_TIO_OWNER.REPORTER_STATUS, column LASTMODIFIED.
ORA-01830: format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

I can exclude the sub second accuracy from my data, then it imports just fine, but obviously that is sub-optimal. How do I get `sqlldr` to accept these data strings?

PS. I have checked with SQL Developer and see the target table is configured to have the same number of decimals.

**Updated with loader control file**

```
 load data
  2   infile 'REPORTER_JOURNAL.csv'
  3   into table ORA_TIO_OWNER.REPORTER_JOURNAL
  4   fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
  5   ( CHRONO DATE "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF", SERIAL INTEGER EXTERNAL, SERVERNAME CHAR, SERVERSERIAL INTEGER EXTERNAL, TEXT1 CHAR, TEXT10 CHAR, TEXT11 CHAR, TEXT12 CHAR, TEXT13 CHAR, TEXT14 CHAR, TEXT15 CHAR, TEXT16 CHAR, TEXT2 CHAR, TEXT3 CHAR, TEXT4 CHAR, TEXT5 CHAR, TEXT6 CHAR, TEXT7 CHAR, TEXT8 CHAR, TEXT9 CHAR, USERID INTEGER EXTERNAL )
```

That is non-functioning and giving `ORA-01821: date format not recognized` If I hack off the `.FF` it will load the cut down version of dates.

P.S. Don't worry about the differing table names. I am migrating a whole pile of data from DB2 to Oracle and there are many tables, but the problem is the same across them all

Comment: Please provide your sql loader code, so that can look at and help you

Comment: Question updated with the loader control file

Comment: What is the data type of `LASTMODIFIED`?

Comment: All my target time fields are `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
LASTMODIFIED timestamp "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF"
```

I can run the following on 11.2.0.4 and 19c without errors:

```
$ cat ld.dat
"2020-01-05-16.32.02.070000"
$ cat ld.ctl
load data
infile 'ld.dat'
into table t 
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
(c timestamp "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF")
$ sqlldr userid=system/oracle data=ld.dat control=ld.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mon Jun 8 11:28:14 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
$ sqlplus system/oracle 
SQL> select * from t;

C
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-JAN-20 04.32.02.070000 PM

SQL> desc t;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C                          TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME
                             ZONE
```

Comment: that gives: `ORA-01821: date format not recognized` and bombs out the loader

Comment: What is your 4 digits Oracle version ?

Comment: Oracle version: 12.1.0.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (see my updated answer).

Comment: Try to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example